# App Engine indexes stuck in building and deleting states

Tags: google-app-engine

I introduced a new entity in the latest version of my application and index building for it is stuck in "Building" state for more than 12 hours already even though there were no entities of that kind in the database yet.

I tried update_indexes and I tried to redeploy my app. Then I deleted all indexes from index.yaml and tried vacuum_indexes. Now all other indexes are stuck in the "Deleting" state for the same period of time. All additional calls to vacuum_indexes produces this message:

"6 indexes were not deleted.  Most likely this is because they no longer exist."

The 6 indexes that are then listed are the ones that are in the "Building" state.

So none of the indexes are in the "Error" state but they wouldn't finish building and deleting. I have about 400 entities in the datastore and index building never took more than a few minutes before.

ANSWER: More than 20 hours later the indexes finally finished building and deleted indexes disappeared.

Comment: Seems like these indexes oddly took long to build.  Could you post this as a self-answer and accept so the question may be considered resolved?